# Scrolling for a div present inside the while loop in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

```
<?php
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array ($res2)) 
{
  //echo "<div id='filmstrip' style='float:left;overflow-x:Scroll;width:920px;margin:0 auto; background:#f9f9f9; padding:10px; height:130px;overflow-y:hidden;white-space: nowrap;'>";
  echo '<div id="sortable1"  class="connectedSortable">';
  echo "<img id='$row2[id]'  style='width:100px;float:left;height:100px;border:2px solid #b06c1c;border-radius:10px;' src=\"user_data/" . $row2['filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" /><br />";
  //echo "</div>";
  echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Here I am showing the images from table to in a div called `sortable1`. I want that `img` to scroll horizontally. When i applied the CSS for `sortable1`, the scroll bar is coming for each and every image but not to div which is holding all the images. Can any one please suggest the solution? I am new to PHP and Jquery.

Comment: you have to do two changes, 1. Get common div element("div with id sortable1") outside of "while" loop. 2. Apply the all style (float:left;overflow-x:Scroll;width:920px;margin:0 auto; background:#f9f9f9; padding:10px; height:130px;overflow-y:hidden;white-space: nowrap;) to this "sortable1 div" and remove if any other style applied on this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but ist not working....is aproblem with css or php?<?php
    echo '<div id="sortable1" style="float:left;overflow-x:Scroll;width:920px;margin:0 auto; background:#f9f9f9; padding:10px; height:130px;overflow-y:hidden;white-space: nowrap;">';

while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array ($res2)) 
{
echo "<img id='$row2[id]'  style='width:100px;float:left;height:100px;border:2px solid #b06c1c;border-radius:10px;' src=\"user_data/" . $row2['filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" /><br />";
}
echo "</div>";
?>

Comment: To give more appropriate suggestion post your generated html with css applied on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should probably be:

```
<?php
echo "<div id='filmstrip' style='float:left;overflow-x:Scroll;width:920px;margin:0 auto; background:#f9f9f9; padding:10px; height:130px;overflow-y:hidden;white-space: nowrap;'>";
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array ($res2)) 
{
  echo '<div id="sortable1"  class="connectedSortable">';
  echo "<img id='$row2[id]'  style='width:100px;float:left;height:100px;border:2px solid #b06c1c;border-radius:10px;' src=\"user_data/" . $row2['filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" /><br />";
  echo '</div>';
}
echo "</div>";
?>
```